# How do you remove SSL encryption after letsencrypt set up forced SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt

I chose to force https on my server when setting up let's encrypt, not realizing what a NIGHTMARE it would cause for my Node.js WebSocket server. Nothing that I've found online works to get a secure WebSocket connection up and running. (Probably because I'm using Apache for everything aside from WebSockets)

So I've decided to just disable SSL site-wide. I don't have any real use for it as my server is strictly for development anyway.

I've tried the method [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-remove-disable-letsencrypt-on-apache-ubuntu-16-04-server) But Apache reports that the site is already disabled. So I cleared the cache on my browser and even tried to visit the site incognito to no avail.

I also looked at the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-disable-letsencrypt-redirect-all-requests-to-secure-https-access) but NONE of my site-available contain the lines that are mentioned.

Then I saw [this](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/always-redirect-to-https/10838/2) post but my apache2.conf file did not contain the lines he mentioned either.

I'm puling my hair out.

Comment: You are right. If something is a little different the whole operation to get a SSL certificate is an huge pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, here's what I did to solve it.

I saw a configuration file named `<sitenam>-le-ssl.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` So I tried `a2dissite <sitename>-le-ssl.conf`

But Apache said "the file doesn't exist"

So I copied that file to my home directory with `cp <sitename>-le-ssl.conf ~`(AND YOU SHOULD TOO! just in case...)

Then I deleted that file with `sudo rm <sitename>-le-ssl.conf`

Then, restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Finally, clear the cache on your browser and visit your site. Everything *should* be back to normal now.

No idea why letsencrypt set up my server in such an odd way. It didn't follow ANY of the standards that others said it should.

Hope this helps someone in the future.